# SOLR automatically displays all Indexed pages

Tags: mysql, xml, database, search, solr

I'm not sure a conclusive answer is possible, but perhaps pointing me in the right direction can help.

I installed Apache SOLR on my own server. It's integrated into Wordpress in that I can index my WP posts as searchable pages in SOLR. I'm using the popular WPSOLR plug-in to add the search box to my Wordpress site using a shortcode.

The problem is, when my webpage is loaded it automatically displays every single page I've indexed to SOLR, as if the user performed a search query for my entire websites indexed pages.

With over 100,000 indexed pages, this crashes the page most times. It's basically performing the exact same effect as if a user performed a 'blank' search query (thus returning every single page in my index), but it'ss automatically happening on page load. Its odd, and im baffled by it.

Anyone visiting my website gets a giant "100,000+ pages found" as soon as they visit.

Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: I'm surprised you can't tweak it right from WP admin interface, I can't check right now.. 

But for sure you can [alter the query](https://www.wpsolr.com/guide/actions-and-filters/search-query-query/) to add custom filters and/or limit the number of results returned. 

You might also want to restrict the [fields list](https://www.wpsolr.com/guide/actions-and-filters/search-query-fields-list/) to return since loading all fields can drastically slows down search.

Comment: Tell me about it. The lack of (meaningful) configuration options within the WPSolr UI is surprising. Anyway, I've been focusing on documentation directly at the SOLR website, and havent checked out this WPSOLR documentation you provided - this seems helpful

Comment: Could you post results of  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%size';  and  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_select_limit'?